# How to fetch fetch one column lazily with a jOOQ active record

Tags: java, postgresql, activerecord, lazy-loading, jooq

I have a PostgreSQL table that defines a couple of small simple columns and one column `data` that stores large binary data:

```sql
create table my_table
(
    id          serial primary key,
    data        bytea  not null,
    description text
);
```

When I'm fetching rows of this table through jOOQ (into a `MyTableRecord`), jOOQ fetches every column at once. I know jOOQ supports lazy fetching of records via `fetchLazy()` and `stream()`, but that applies only on the level of rows, not individual columns.

Thus, the resulting `MyTableRecord` class always has a simple getter for `data` stored in memory:

```java
...
public byte[] getData() {
    return (byte[]) get(1);
}
...
```

This means that whenever I want to work with an active record instance of `MyTableRecord` I have to fetch all the data from DB, even when I don't need it.
How can I change the behaviour of jOOQ/MyTableRecord to fetch the `data` column lazily, only when I first call `.getData()` on the record object?

I know this problem can be solved by a workaround where I offload the binary data to another table and introduce a 1:1 foreign key relationship, but that is a complication I'm not looking for, as it would (among other issues) require adding a join operation each time to my data queries.

Comment: Not lazy, but I imagine you could select the columns you want and the use `into` to then turn it into a `MyTableRecord`: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.17/manual/sql-execution/fetching/record-vs-tablerecord/

Comment: @scrhartley yeah, but then when I actually want to load the data, I'd have to call `setData(byte[])` on the record object, which raises the `changed` flag, and so on... I want this fetching to be done behind the scenes without the need to manipulate the record.

Comment: If you literally just want to retrieve the data, then you could turn off that functionality and not attach the records: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.18/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-attach-records/

Comment: No, I want to be able to modify the data (that's what I meant by updatable/active record), I just want to avoid fetching the byte array when not needed by postponing the action until the first `getData()` is called.

Comment: Still not what you want: rather than calling `setData(byte[])`, `refresh()` would not have the problem of the `changed` flag, but would result in over-fetching and wouldn't get all the data in the collection of records in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with your `MyTableRecord` even when you don't fetch all columns. Just make sure you include the primary key:

```java
Result<MyTableRecord> result =
ctx.select(MY_TABLE.ID, MY_TABLE.DESCRIPTION)
   .from(MY_TABLE)
   .fetchInto(MY_TABLE);
```

Now, when you're ready, refresh the record in question:

```java
myTableRecord.refresh(MY_TABLE.DATA);
```

You can also fetch *some* of those values up front, and others only later, like this:

```java
Result<MyTableRecord> result =
ctx.select(
      MY_TABLE.ID, 
      MY_TABLE.DESCRIPTION,
      when(MY_TABLE.ID.in(1, 2, 3), MY_TABLE.HEAVY_COL1).as(MY_TABLE.DATA))
   .from(MY_TABLE)
   .fetchInto(MY_TABLE);
```

Obviously, this approach is prone to [N+1 queries](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/reference/dont-do-this/dont-do-this-n-plus-one/), but you seem to have measured the difference and are certain that N queries are faster/better for you, *in this case*.

#### A remark on other RDBMS

Since you're using PostgreSQL, there's probably no other way, but other RDBMS support JDBC's `Clob` and `Blob` APIs, which serve as pointers towards the actual LOB data. By default, jOOQ always fetches everything eagerly, but you can make jOOQ expose those JDBC `Clob` or `Blob` types instead, in order to read the binary data only later on *without* a second query:

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/reference/reference-data-types/data-types-lobs/